# Camel FileConsumer does not handle Exchange but recognizes file

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a spring-boot-application standalone application which uses apache camel to consume a single file, convert it and send the contents to a rest endpoint.

## The current working setup

The pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.thehandofnod</groupId>
<artifactId>recommenderclient</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>recommenderclient</name>
<description>Client application which communicates with the different Recommender</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
<camel-spring-boot-starter-version>2.25.2</camel-spring-boot-starter-version>
<camel-bindy-version>2.25.2</camel-bindy-version>
<camel-jackson-starter-version>2.25.2</camel-jackson-starter-version>
<camel-http-starter-version>2.25.2</camel-http-starter-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${camel-spring-boot-starter-version}</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
 
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-bindy-starter -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-bindy-starter</artifactId>
  <version>${camel-bindy-version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-jackson-starter -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
  <version>${camel-jackson-starter-version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-jetty-starter -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-http-starter</artifactId>
  <version>${camel-http-starter-version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
<dependency>  
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
<!-- DB dependencies
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcc</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-webtestclient</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>enforce</id>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <dependencyConvergence/>
          </rules>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>enforce</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
            <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-docs</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <backend>html</backend>
                        <doctype>book</doctype>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-restdocs-asciidoctor</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-restdocs.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

As you can see I currently use the dependency `spring-boot-starter-web` to keep the application and therefore the camel routes running. I do this because otherwise the `FileConsumer` just recognizes the file, creates the exchange but does not route it to the endpoint for processing. That's where my question starts.

## The problem

If I **don't use** the dependency `spring-boot-starter-web` but want my standalone application to run just **only once** the routes are just started and shutdown without doing anything (see 'The wished setup')

The problem seems to be that the method `ScheduledBatchPollingConsumer#isBatchAllowed` **sometimes** returns **false** and sometimes returns **true**. I can't figure out why but to me it seems a timing problem because if I have luck the file is consumed and processed and if I don't have luck the `Exchange` is not processed.

## The wished setup

So I don't want to use the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency and I don't want to keep the application running. This should be my wished configuration:

`application.properties`

```
camel.component.properties.encoding=UTF-8
# general spring-boot settings
#camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true
#camel.springboot.name=Recommender
# I don't want to keep it running! Shutdown after file was processed is what I wish for.
#camel.springboot.endpoint-bridge-error-handler=true
#camel.springboot.log-mask=true

# common attributes
projectID=2
# customer data route & properties
customerdata.from=file:D:\\projects\\TMP\\RecommenderClientTests\\source?fileName=CUSTOMER_DATA.csv&move=\..\processed&initialDelay=2000&delay=1000
customerdata.to=direct:TransmitCustomerData


# transmit customer data route & properties
transmitcustomerdata.from=direct:TransmitCustomerData
#transmitcustomerdata.to=file:D:\\projects\\TMP\\Camel\\to\\customer?    tempFileName=CustomerRequest_tmp.txt&fileName=Customer.json
transmitcustomerdata.to=http://u086:9002/prioritizer/project/customer/transmit?\
                        bridgeEndpoint=false&\
                        throwExceptionOnFailure=false&\
                        httpMethod=POST
transmitcustomerdata.append=false

# archive
archiv=file:D:\\projects\\TMP\\RecommenderClientTests\\archiv?    fileName=$simple{exchangeId}-$simple{date:now:yyyyMMddHHmm}&fileExist=Append
```

## The question

How can I configure the file endpoint so that the file is always consumed **and processed** and the routes are shutdown **afterwards**?

Answer (score 0):

There are options you can configure to shutdown after N messages processed, or being idel for more than N seconds, or after N time etc.

For example

```
 camel.springboot.duration-max-messages = 1
```

See more at the docs: https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/latest/spring-boot.html

Comment: I tried with 
`camel.springboot.duration-max-messages=1
camel.springboot.duration-max-seconds=10`
but neither of these work. The only way I can keep the routes running is still with `spring-boot-starter-web`. Maybe I use some incompatible versions of spring-boot and camel?

Comment: Yeah that was a bug in some versions where this didnt work properly, also Camel 3.x is the main active version so upgrade if you can.